# How to pass array of objects as global variable in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an array of objects that I have passed from JS to GS.
Here is an example of how the array of object may look like (changes depending on user input)

```
var playersArray = 
[
{number=1, 
role=Arsonist, 
deathStatus=false, 
guardianTargetStatus=false, 
executionerTargetStatus=false, 
roleblockStatus=false}, 

{number=2, 
role=Arsonist, 
deathStatus=false, 
guardianTargetStatus=false, 
executionerTargetStatus=false, 
roleblockStatus=false}, 

{number=3, role=Arsonist, 
deathStatus=false, 
guardianTargetStatus=false, 
executionerTargetStatus=false, 
roleblockStatus=false}
]
```

Throughout my code I need to call some data from this array. For example

```
var roleList = playersArray.map(function(role) {return role.role;});
Browser.msgBox(playersArray[1]["role"]);
```

When I pass this playersArray directly between functions, everything worls fine.
Unfortunately for one of my functions I need to pull this array without passing it directly.

I have therefore set playerArray as a Property within GS

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('playersArray', JSON.stringify(playersArray));
```

I am then using getProperty inside relevant function to get this array:

```
var playersArray = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('playersArray'); 
  playersArray = playersArray.replace(/\"/g, "").replace(/\:/g, "=");
  playersArray = playersArray.split(",");
```

For some reason the function cannot see the array properly when I do that:

```
var roleList = playersArray.map(function(role) {return role.role;});
Browser.msgBox(playersArray[1]["role"]);
```

Please help me solve this. If the solution I am using for passing the array as global is not viable, I am happy to see other solutions. But it has to be global because I cannot pass the array directly between functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put the array object to PropertiesService.
- When you retrieve the array object from PropertiesService, you want to use `playersArray` as an array object.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
var playersArray = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('playersArray');
playersArray = playersArray.replace(/\"/g, "").replace(/\:/g, "=");
playersArray = playersArray.split(",");
```

#### To:

```
var playersArray = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('playersArray');
playersArray = JSON.parse(playersArray);
```

#### Note:

- Please be careful the quotas of PropertiesService.

  - Properties value size is 9kB / val
  - Properties total storage is 500kB / property store
- I thought that in your script, `playersArray` might be like `var playersArray = [{number: 1, role: "Arsonist", deathStatus: false, guardianTargetStatus: false, executionerTargetStatus: false, roleblockStatus: false},,,]`. Because before the object is put to PropertiesService, `Browser.msgBox(playersArray[1]["role"])` works. And when you see `playersArray` by `Logger.log(playersArray)`, you might see like `var playersArray = [{number=1, role=Arsonist, deathStatus=false, guardianTargetStatus=false, executionerTargetStatus=false, roleblockStatus=false},,,]`. When `playersArray` is object,  when the object is seen by `Logger.log(playersArray)`, `:` is converted to `=`. I think that this is the specification of Google Apps Script. So the object put to PropertiesService using `JSON.stringify()` can be converted to the object using `JSON.parse()`.

#### References:

- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves my problem. I have spent 4 days trying to go around it and the solution was so close :)

Comment: @Ilya Perelman Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.